# Subscribe button desing and After click unSubscribe

Tags: html, css

I Want to design a subscribe button.
When user subscribes another user, the button shuld change text to `UnSubscribe`
Like: YouTube

href="#unsubscribe"

href="#subscribe"

href="#login_required

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#unsubscribe" class="btn" type="button">Subscribe</a>
<a href="#subscribe" class="btn" type="button">UnSubscribe</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **jQuery/Javascript** to implement this, check the text present inside the button and according to the basis of text present inside the button change the text to `subscribe` & `unsubscribe`. Like:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).text() == 'Subscribe') {
    $(this).text('UnSubscribe');
    $(this).attr('href', '#subscribe');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Subscribe');
    $(this).attr('href', '#unsubscribe');
  }
});
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).text() == 'Subscribe') {
    $(this).text('UnSubscribe');
    $(this).attr('href', '#subscribe');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Subscribe');
    $(this).attr('href', '#unsubscribe');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#unsubscribe" class="btn" type="button">Subscribe</a>
<a href="#subscribe" class="btn" type="button">UnSubscribe</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. But the url's sud be change with text

Comment: @maks Updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks...Its changing url in live editor. and on web but just changing with #url only on screen. don't send data to server.. something missing.. Please help more...

Comment: @maks I've only shown the front end part here. For sending data to the server on click you need to use **AJAX**. Using AJAX you'll be able to send the data to the server and conditionally apply the JS I've given. AJAX - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp